# Hard case with array which using hases inside (ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have:
`a = [{:a=1,"b=2,:c=3},{:a=4,:b=5,:c=6},..]` (including 2 items with 3 keys)
`b = [{:d=7},{:d=8},...]` (including 2 items with 1 key)

At final I need to have 2 items with 4 keys:
`a = [{:a=1,:b=2,:c=3,:d=7},{:a=4,:b=5,:c=6,:d=8},..]`

Please help, tried to do the following:

```
a.each do |item|
   b.each do |view|
     item.merge!(view)      
   end
end
```

But at final I have in two items the same dates as for item one in array b (d=7).

Comment: {a=1,b=2,c=3} is this hash valid? maybe you meant {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your definitions of a and b are not very valid. You need to use either symbols or strings a is not a valid key for a hash. Also you should use => to point a key to value.
Here is how you can achieve what you want to do:

```
a = [{:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3},{:a=>4,:b=>5,:c=>6}]
b =[{:d=>7}, {:d=>8}]
a.zip(b) do |x,y|
  x.merge!(y)
end
```

Zip performs the operation on each matching pair of elements in a and b - precisely what you want.

Comment: I think you are missing a `.map` on the end of your `zip`?

Comment: I have tried it in my irb. After execution of the code I have pasted, the contents of a is `[{:c=>3, :a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>7}, {:c=>6, :a=>4, :b=>5, :d=>8}]`, which is what we want.